# Android build variant for different config

Tags: android, android-build

I am working on project for three customer where code remains unchanged but the configuration and some settings related to notification will get changed and it's written in property file.Now what i am doing is every time i will go and change the property file and build it for specific customer.
I have seen same type of solution like [creating `apk` for different API levels](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/multiple-apks/api.html).Checked [Building multiple editions of `apk`](http://blog.robustastudio.com/mobile-development/android/building-multiple-editions-of-android-app-gradle/).

What i need is say if i have written three property file for three different customer, then how should i mention in `build.gradle` file to choose specific file for specific build.?

Answer (score 1):

It may help you.

[Multiple apks](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/multiple-apks/api.html)

[Publishing Multiple apks](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html)

Comment: Second link is not the same and can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use flavor it will fulfill your task.Feel its power.
Ask me if you get any problem using it. Here is the link.

http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html

Mark this answer up..it it helps.. :)